# Dracula theme (colors) for zsh not propagating

Tags: zsh

The [Dracula theme](https://draculatheme.com/zsh/) for Zsh makes it seem by following the instructions there you'll not only get the prompt but the colors as well. Am i missing something?

This is what i got.
[image]

This is what it should look like.

[image]

Any help will be apprecited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the proper way—as I would think the `dracula.zsh-theme` file located in `Users/your_root_folder/.oh-my-zsh/themes/dracula.zsh-theme` would've included colors for the theme...

That being said I went to the [terminal](https://draculatheme.com/terminal/) version of the dracula theme and just downloaded it and installed `(e.g. Preferences/profiles/settings(gear-icon)/import` it, then set it as the default. And wa-la (or blah-blah) it worked!